# Static member cannot be used on protocol meta type

Tags: ios, swift, proxy, protocols, associated-types

What I am trying to accomplish is to make Proxy protocol that will route my class to appropriate service.
I have 3 types of service per 1 proxy:OnlineService,OfflineService,DemoService each for one of modes (online, offline,demo).

I created protocol :

```
protocol Proxy {
    associatedtype ServiceProtocol
    associatedtype OfflineServiceType: OfflineService
    associatedtype OnlineServiceType: WebService
    associatedtype DemoServiceType: DemoService
}

extension Proxy {
    static var service: ServiceProtocol.Type {
        if isOnlineMode() {
            return OfflineServiceType.self as! ServiceProtocol.Type
        } else if isDemoMode(){
            return DemoServiceType.self as! ServiceProtocol.Type
        }else{
            return OnlineServiceType.self as! ServiceProtocol.Type
        }
    }
}
```

and then on Customer proxy class

```
class CustomersServiceProxy: Proxy, CustomersService {
    typealias ServiceProtocol = CustomersService
    typealias OfflineServiceType = CustomersOfflineService
    typealias OnlineServiceType = CustomerWebService

    public static func customerDetails(for customer: Customer, completion: @escaping (CustomerDetails) -> Void) {
        service.customerDetails(for: customer, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

But I got error:

> Static member 'customerDetails' cannot be used on protocol metataype 'CustomerServiceProxy.ServiceProtocol.Protocol' (aka 'CustomerService.Protocol').

I suggest that this happens because Proxy service variable is returning CustomerService.Type instead of Type that is conforming to CustomerService. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Answer (score -2):

well, u r missing a step, for example:

```
protocol Proxcy {}

extention Proxcy {
   static func a() { print("A")
}

struct A: Proxcy {}

struct B: Proxcy {
   A.a()
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)